# My foregrund that publish a notification periodically doesn't work in Android 13, but it works in Android 8.1 (MAUI Android)

Tags: c#, maui

By the moment for learning purposes, I want to create an application that use a foreground to run always in the device and every 5 seconds, publish a notification.

It works in Android 8.1, but in Android 13 it doesn't work.

The code is this:

Alarm service with the logic when to publish a notification.

```
    public class ServicioAlarmas : IServicioAlarmas
    {
        private Task? _taskTimer;
        private readonly PeriodicTimer _timer;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private int _numeroNotificacion = 0;
    
    
    
    
        public ServicioAlarmas(ILocalizadorHelper paramLocalizadorHelper)
        {
            _timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            _localizadorHelper = paramLocalizadorHelper;
        }
    
    
    
    
        public delegate void NotificacionNecesariaEventHandler(string paramStrMensajeNotificacion);
        public event NotificacionNecesariaEventHandler NotificacionNecesariaEvent;
    
        private void OnNotificacionNecesaria(string paramStrMensajeNotificacion)
        {
            NotificacionNecesariaEvent?.Invoke(paramStrMensajeNotificacion);
        }
    
    
    
    
        public void Iniciar()
        {
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _taskTimer = DoWorkAsync();
        }
    
    
        public async void DetenerAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_taskTimer == null) return;
    
                _cts.Cancel();
                await _taskTimer;
                _cts.Dispose();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    
    
    
    
        private async Task DoWorkAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(_cts.Token))
                {
                    _numeroNotificacion = _numeroNotificacion + 1;
                    OnNotificacionNecesaria($"Número Notificacion: {_numeroNotificacion}.");
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }


This is the foreground service:

[Service]
public class AlarmasForegroundService : Service
{
    private IServicioAlarmas _servicioAlarmas;

    private string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1000";
    private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "notification";
    private NotificationManager _notificationManager;




    private void StartForegroundService()
    {
        _notificationManager = (GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager)!;

        createNotificationChannel(_notificationManager);


        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.logo32x32)
            .SetAutoCancel(false)
            .SetOngoing(false)
            .Build();
        StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }


    private NotificationChannel? createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationMnaManager)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O) return null;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationImportance.Default);
        notificationMnaManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);

        return channel;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        StartForegroundService();
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }




    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        _servicioAlarmas = MauiApplication.Current.Services.GetService<IServicioAlarmas>()!;
        _servicioAlarmas.NotificacionNecesariaEvent += OnNotificacionNecesariaHandler;
        _servicioAlarmas.Iniciar();
    }



    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        _servicioAlarmas.NotificacionNecesariaEvent -= OnNotificacionNecesariaHandler;
        _servicioAlarmas.DetenerAsync();

        base.OnDestroy();
    }




    public void Iniciar()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AlarmasForegroundService));
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);
    }


    public void Detener()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AlarmasForegroundService));
        Android.App.Application.Context.StopService(intent);
    }





    private void OnNotificacionNecesariaHandler(string paramStrMensajeAlarma)
    {
        try
        {
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetContentTitle("Servicio trabajando (Título)")
                .SetContentText(paramStrMensajeAlarma)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.logo32x32)
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                .SetAutoCancel(false)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();


            _notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem in Android 13 is that the foreground is only run once, because it runs this code:

```
private NotificationChannel? createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationMnaManager)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O) return null;

    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationImportance.Default);
    notificationMnaManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);

    return channel;
}
```

But this code is not run:

```
private void OnNotificacionNecesariaHandler(string paramStrMensajeAlarma)
    {
        try
        {
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetContentTitle("Servicio trabajando (Título)")
                .SetContentText(paramStrMensajeAlarma)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.logo32x32)
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                .SetAutoCancel(false)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();


            _notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Because this code in the AlarmasService is run only once:

```
private async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(_cts.Token))
            {
                _numeroNotificacion = _numeroNotificacion + 1;
                Location? miLocalizacion = await _localizadorHelper.GetUltimaLocalizacionConocidaAsync();

                OnNotificacionNecesaria($"Número Notificacion: {_numeroNotificacion}. Coordenadas: {miLocalizacion.Latitude}, {miLocalizacion.Longitude}");
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

However, if in DoWork, I comment the line that notify the event, the the code inside the while is running until I stop the foreground service.

So the problem it seems in the event, but I don't understand why the code works in Android 8.1 and not in Android 13.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have tried using IMessenger of CommunityToolkit, the WeakReferenceMessenger and it works. So I guess there is some problem with the event.

How could I solve the problem with events? Or could I use the messenger like events?

Thanks.

Comment: About notification, you can refer to this doc: [Notification permission affects foreground service appearance](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#notification-permission-fgs-appearance). If you have done it, but the foreground is only run once and no error occurs, you can report it on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).